# How to download JS Bin to my computer to code

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsbin

I'm new to JavaSript, and I like [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), but on desktop no thing is the same for development. Is there a way to work with JS Bin without access to the website?

Comment: I don't know why was this question closed as "not a real question". It's trivial to tell what is being asked here. It is not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and it certainly can be reasonably answered (in which I hopefully succeeded) even in its original form. The only problem that it had was that the English needed some copy editing (which I did). I think it's better to fix the minor problems with English rather than discourage new users by flagging their first questions as not real questions when it is clearly not the case.

Comment: overzealous SO user close this question again?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to install it on your own computer and it is a great way to start experimenting with server-side JavaScript because JS Bin itself is itself written in JavaScript. The [source code of JS Bin](https://github.com/remy/jsbin) is available on GitHub and the [jsbin module](https://npmjs.org/package/jsbin) is available for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

First you have to [install Node.js](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs). Then you will have to install the [jsbin module](https://npmjs.org/package/jsbin) with a command:

```
npm install jsbin
```

And the `jsbin` command should now be available. If you run it you should have a fully functional version of JS Bin available at `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: `npm install jsbin` don't work for me - it throws an error I don't understand: "npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo EAGAIN
npm ERR!     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)"

Comment: @Matt, is that working for you now? it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Matt, could be a few things. Can you post it as it's own question along with the errors. Then send me the link so I can forward it to a few people. Thanks.

Comment: @JGallardo: I've created a question as you suggested [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19988889/1016343)