# Python not found as dependency during ' npm jsbin' installation. What is missing?

Tags: python, npm, jsbin

This question was created from issues I've encountered while trying to install jsbin locally. [JGallardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120027/jgallardo) has asked me to create a question from it, because originally I've posted comments in the [original Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13133999/1016343) (please follow the link to see what it was about).

**Update:** Since the Windows tag has been removed by reviewers, let me note that I am having the issues on a **Windows 7** machine.

The command `npm install jsbin` don't work for me - it throws an error I don't understand: 
`"npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo EAGAIN npm ERR! at errnoException (dns.js:37:11) npm ERR! at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)"`

I've set up a proxy server, which is required in my case as I found: 
`npm config set proxy=http://servername:port`. 
Now it is fetching files, when I call `npm install jsbin` into the 
`"c:\users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache"` 
directory - but it is running very long. Now it is saying `"can't find python executable"` - do you know which dependency this is? How can I install the python package if that is required?

After getting the error above, I have also tried to install `npn install python` before running `npn install jsbin`. It also did not work, I am still getting the error 
`"Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable."`

Can you help to get jsbin installed locally? Why can't npm find the python package although it seems to be installed?

**N.B.** I now have also installed the official Python interpreter from the [official source](http://www.python.org/getit/) and verified that it is available through the `path`environment variable:

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.12 (x64) and npm.

C:\>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Also, I've set up the `PYTHON`environment variable to the path `C:\Python33` where the python system was installed to.

The error I am getting is:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Python33\node_modules\jsbin\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: I have to ask, and I apologize. Is the python.exe on your system path?

Comment: @K.Niemczyk - Good question! `npm install python`downloads a python package which is created in the npm-cache. Inside `C:\Users\...\npm-cache\python\0.0.2\package\lib` there is a `python.js` file, but no `python.exe`. I don't know the purpose of this lib, but it seems to be too small for a complete python interpreter.

Comment: I'd recommend manually putting the path to a python interpreter on your sys path and retry it. Sometimes these things are head slappers in retrospect.

Comment: @K.Niemczyk: I've updated my question - Python is installed, available in the path but the issues are still there.

Comment: Hmm: Have you consulted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies?rq=1) question? Sounds like a similar problem.

Comment: @K.Niemczyk: Thank you for sharing the link, I've tried it but in my case there is still an error (see my update to the question).

Comment: One more thing. I wonder if jsbin has a hidden dependency on the npm python module (npm install python). That module seems to focus on interacting with long-running child processes, which seems 'promising'. I'll give it a whirl tonight when I get home to see if I can duplicate what you have going here.

Comment: That would be great, thank you!

Comment: I tried on two platforms, OSX and Windows 7. OSX worked fine and I can run jsbin without problems. On windows it failed but it looks more due to the fact that I'm missing other stuff that the dependencies of jsbin require. Unfortunately, I don't think I can attempt to help much further. Good luck.

Comment: @K.Niemczyk: Thank you for your efforts. At least I know now that it is a platform (Windows) related issue.

Comment: @Matt did you end up getting it working? I'm running into the same issue. Is it related to the "gyp ERR! System Windows_NT..." because I am on Windows 8.1

Comment: @woojoo666: No, unfortunately not. I don't know what else I could try. In my case, it is Win7/64 bit.

Comment: I was able to find a solution [here](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/issues/353#issuecomment-30627120). Remember to install OpenSSL first, and hope it works for you!

Comment: @woojoo666: I've installed [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/), then I tried `git clone https://github.com/remy/jsbin.git` as described in the [post](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/issues/353#issuecomment-30627120) but got the error `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/remy/jsbin.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com`

Comment: hmm, perhaps a firewall or something? Did u try using the powershell provided by the github app?

Comment: @woojoo666: I used the GitShell to invoke the command above.

Comment: can you git anything else? [this](http://www.dexterindustries.com/forum/?topic=error-couldnt-resolve-host-github-com) says it might be a problem with the internet. Well if all else fails I'm sure you can just download the repo as a zip from the right-panel of [the jsbin github page](https://github.com/remy/jsbin))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find out why NPN wasn't installing python, but then I tried it with a different installer, [choco (or Chocolatey)](https://chocolatey.org/), which succeeded.

Steps are:

1. Install Chocolatey. See [Chocolatey website](https://chocolatey.org/) for instructions
2. Open administrator console, then do the following:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>`**`choco install python`**

```xml
!!ATTENTION!!
The next version of Chocolatey (v0.9.9) will require -y to perform
  behaviors that change state without prompting for confirmation. Start
  using it now in your automated scripts.

  For details on the all new Chocolatey, visit http://bit.ly/new_choco
Chocolatey (v0.9.8.33) is installing 'python' and dependencies. 
By installing you accept the license for 'python' and each dependency you are installing.

python v3.4.3
Using this proxyserver: defrceprx02.ey.net:8443
Downloading python 64 bit
  from 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/python-3.4.3.amd64.msi'
Using this proxyserver: defrceprx02.ey.net:8443
Installing python...
python has been installed.
python has finished successfully! The chocolatey gods have answered your request!
PATH environment variable does not have C:\tools\python in it. Adding...
Finished installing 'python' and dependencies - if errors not shown in console, none detected. 
Check log for errors if unsure.
```

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>`